# JList is not updated when calling update from another class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist

I have two classes, each class is a panel of a JTabbedPane. These classes implement panels with JTable (the first panel) and JList (the second panel). The task is to copy selected items from JTable to JList. The button which listens to the event of adding new items from JTable to JList, is in the first class. I have the following code in the button's listener `actionPerformed()`:

```
int[] selection = aJTable.getSelectedRows();
for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++)
{
      selection[i] = aJTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selection[i]);
      String mp = (String)aJTable.getValueAt(selection[i], 0);

      // ProfileView is a singleton
      ProfileView.getInstance().getMPModelList().addElement(mp);        
}
```

The ListModel is updated, if I print it before and after inserting a new element, the new element is added to the list. But this new item is not visible in the list, so the list is not updated. I used repaint and revalidate, but it doesn't work.

Why can't I update the list from another class? I actually have two JLists in the second class, but the second one is updated by clicking the button on the same panel, it works perfect, but I can't do the same from another class, using the same algorithm (listModel.addElement(pMP)).

Update. The code of the first class (with JTable):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private MPTable2 aTable = new MPTable2(); 
    private final String aTitle = "Title";
    private final Dimension aSize = new Dimension(400, 500);
    private JTable aJTable;

    public Test1()
    {
        setBorder(new TitledBorder(aTitle)); 
        setPreferredSize(aSize); 
        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
        tablePanel.setVisible(true); 
        aJTable = new JTable(aTable);
        JScrollPane tableContainer = new JScrollPane(aJTable); 
        tablePanel.add(tableContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add MP"); 
        add(addButton, BorderLayout.EAST); 

        addButton.addActionListener(this); 
        aTable.fillTable();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent pAction)
    {
        int[] selection = aJTable.getSelectedRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++)
        {
            selection[i] = aJTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selection[i]);
            String mp = (String)aJTable.getModel().getValueAt(selection[i], 1);

            boolean added = test.getInstance().addMP(mp);
            if (added)
            {
                aTable.setValueAt("yes", selection[i], 2); 
                aJTable.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MPTable2 extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModelListener
{

    private final String[] aColumnNames = {
            "One", "Two", "Three", "Four"
    };
    private Object[][] aRowData;
    private int aMPNumber = 0; 


    public MPTable2()
    {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return aMPNumber; 
    }
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount()
    {
        return aColumnNames.length; 
    }
    public void setValueAt(Object pValue, int pRow, int pCol)
    {
        aRowData[pRow][pCol] = pValue; 
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int pRow, int pCol)
    {
        return aRowData[pRow][pCol];
    }
    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent pE)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void fillTable()
    {
        aMPNumber = 3;
        aRowData = new Object[aMPNumber][aColumnNames.length]; 
        int currentDataIndex; 

        for(int i = 1; i < aMPNumber; i++)
        {
            currentDataIndex = 0; 
            this.setValueAt("One", i, currentDataIndex++); 
            this.setValueAt("Two", i, currentDataIndex++); 
            this.setValueAt("Three", i, currentDataIndex++);
            this.setValueAt("Four", i, currentDataIndex++);

        }
    }
}
```

The second class (with JList):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class test extends JPanel
{
    private static final test INSTANCE = new test();
    private JList<String> aList;
    private DefaultListModel<String> aListModel;    

    public test()
    {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBorder(new TitledBorder("TITLE")); 

        JPanel lMPPanel = buildPanel(0); 

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
                lMPPanel, null);
        add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }

    public static test getInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public JPanel buildPanel(int pIndex)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JScrollPane spane = createListPane();
        panel.add(spane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }


    private int getIndex(String pWord, int pIndex)
    {
        int index;
        if (aListModel.size() == 0)
        {
            index = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < aListModel.size(); i++)
            {
                String s = aListModel.getElementAt(i).toLowerCase();
                if (s.compareTo(pWord.toLowerCase()) > 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            index = i;
        }
        return index;
    }
    private JScrollPane createListPane()
    {
        aListModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        aList = new JList<String>(aListModel);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");

        for (String s : list)
            aListModel.addElement(s);

        aList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        aList.setVisibleRowCount(10);

        aList.setPrototypeCellValue("00000000000000000000000000000000000");
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(aList);


        return pane;
    }

    public boolean addMP(String pMP)
    {
        aListModel.insertElementAt(pMP, getIndex(pMP, 0));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends JFrame
{
    private Test()
    {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
            JPanel lCenterPanel = new JPanel(); 
            getContentPane().add(lCenterPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

            JTabbedPane lViews = new JTabbedPane(); 
            buildViews(lViews); 
            lCenterPanel.add(lViews); 
            lCenterPanel.setOpaque(true); 


            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
            pack();  
            setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
            setVisible(true);   
        }

        private void buildViews(JTabbedPane pViews)
        {
            pViews.add("JTable", new Test1()); 
            pViews.add("JList", new test());

        }

        public static void main(String[] pArgs)
        {
            new Test();
        }
    }
```

JList is updated only if to set `private DefaultListModel<String> aListModel` of class `test` to static.

**UPDATE 2.**   Solved by removing Singleton pattern and by passing the instance of `test` class when constructing `Test1` object and then calling addMP method on the instance of `test`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: If it doesn't update then you don't have a proper reference to the ListModel of the JList that is visible on the GUI. I would suggest your method should return the JList that you want to update. Then your code can get the ListModel from the JList and then update the model.

Comment: What does `addElement(String)` look like?

Comment: I get JList via getJList() method of ProfileView. Still it's not updated when I add an element to the list model which I call from the list: ((DefaultListModel<String>)ProfileView.getInstance().getJList().getModel()).addElement(mp);

Comment: addElement(Strig) is a method of the DefaultListModel class. I use DefaultListModel<String> as a ListModel<E> implementation.

Comment: I have no idea of any Shorter, more Self Contained, and Correct (Compilable), Example. Sorry about that. Let me know which other methods you need to understand the question, and I will add it.

Comment: The problem is solved by setting the DefaultListModel<String> instance static. Don't know why.

Comment: @Olga: that is not a solution but a kludge. It suggests that your program design is off. Perhaps your problem is that you're trying to have two distinct objects share state, and that just doesn't happen in Java. Better to pass valid references so that two variables in different classes share the *same object*. Never use the static modifier to fix this type of problem.

Comment: You missed what SSCCE means. SSCCE means: we can take your code, copy it in our IDE without modification, and it compiles. Your example is far from being an SSCCE. The problem is in the code that you don't show.

Comment: Could you please explain (or give a link to read) why it solves when I set to static. I will try to reduce the codes as much as possible and to post them.